# Looking for a simple fade javascript image rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a simple image rotator that rotates images by fading, centers vertically and is accepted by most if not all browsers. I however need to be able to customize the arrow images and place them anywhere i like. Anyone know of one?

If I try to visually show you what I need it would look like this.

< -- My back button    [  image  ]  My next button -- >

I use jquery :) I've given plenty of rotators a shot already but they don't accept images of varying sizes or are not customizable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If all you need is image rotation, why not do it yourself?

It's only a few lines of jQuery and infinitely customizable. :)

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/UNZR5/1/

Comment: Great example, and here's an even simpler, shorter "just fading rotation" example: http://jsfiddle.net/jyd0h3j7/

Answer (score 8):

I generally like to stick to using this one: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It can be as simple or as  complex as you need, and is highly extensible. They also provide heaps of examples for what can be done with it.

Example with next/previous buttons here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://aviathemes.com/aviaslider/?  It is customizable and is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuerytools scrollable by flowplayer. Very lightweight, flexible and they offer a CDN link to there js files so you don't have to load it from your server.

**Scrollable** http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

Make sure to try out all there available scrollable examples.

CDN links can be found at http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html